# How to Get the last 3 added value in specific column in my database

Tags: c#, razor-pages

my data table name is called Shift its data is like below

[image]

i use below syntax to get the last added value

```
Shiftlast = _db.Shift.OrderByDescending(c => c.Id).First(); ---the result is 3500
```

my question is how to get also the before last and before before last values also
which is 2500 and and 152,i need each value to be get in variable as below

```
Shiftlast = _db.Shift.OrderByDescending(c => c.Id).First();
Shiftbeforelast = _db.Shift.OrderByDescending(c => c.Id).??;
Shiftbeforebeforelast = _db.Shift.OrderByDescending(c => c.Id).??;
```

i tried take(3) method but i get error
[image]

Comment: `Take(3)` instead of `First()`

Comment: i need each value to be get in variable as below------                                           
  Shiftlast = _db.Shift.OrderByDescending(c => c.Id).First();                                    Shiftbeforelast = _db.Shift.OrderByDescending(c => c.Id).??;                      
Shiftbeforebeforelast = _db.Shift.OrderByDescending(c => c.Id).??;

Comment: `1.` Edit your question to better describe your needs, instead of adding details to the comments. `2.` The previous suggestion should give you a collection with the found rows. From said collection you can access the three items (you shouldn't need a variable for each and if you do just assign those variables based on the returned collection values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of variable is Shifts? Maybe is `List<T>` and you need to add .ToList();

```cs
Shifts = _db.Shift.OrderByDescending(c => c.Id).Take(3).ToList();
```